# Full or complete graph from supernodes

Tags: igraph

I am trying to do a complete graph from two different groups of nodes. The first one (A) has 8 vertices, and the second one (B) has 147 vertices. My first guess was doing this:

g <- make_empty_graph(directed= FALSE)

g <- g + vertex(c(A, B))

g <- g + graph.full(A, B)

plot(g)

But, unfortunately, this procedure just generated an non-connected graph like this:

[image: graph :(]

Someone could tell me the right path to produce a full connected graph from two or more different groups of nodes in Csárdi's Igraph? I appreciate your help!

Best,

A.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are asking, but it seems to be one of two things.

1. You might want the fully connected graph for all nodes in A or B. You can get that with

   `g = graph.full(c(A,B))`
2. You might want the full graph for a joined to the full graph for B. That is also simple.

   `gA = graph.full(A)
   gB = graph.full(B)
   g = gA + gB`

It is a bit messy to get a nice plot of this though.  This works pretty well.

```
LOA = layout_with_fr(gA)
LOB = layout_with_fr(gB)
LOA[,1] = (LOA[,1] - min(LOA[,1]))/4 + max(LOB[,1]) +0.05
LOA[,2] = (LOA[,2] - min(LOA[,2]))/4 + max(LOB[,2]) +0.05

plot(g, layout=rbind(LOA,LOB), vertex.size=9, margin=-0.2)
```

[image: Two full graphs]

Comment: Thank you so much for your replay. I'd like to compare edge attributes (factor) between two columns. I found this solution:                             `code:     compare.factors <-  subset(data.frame, level1 == "factor", select= level2)
plot(compare.factors, main= "", density= 100, col= "lightblue", border= "black") `